# Flex box - one big div next to few little divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have problem with put `<p>` in `<nav>` next to `<div>`'s which are in columns in flex box. How can I achieve this without any frameworks like Bootstrap?

Here is code:

```
<nav>
        <div><a href="">O mnie</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Moje projekty</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Galeria</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Kontakt</a></div>
        <p>tekst tekst</p>
    </nav>
nav
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
nav div
{
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;

}
nav p
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be next to each other, you have to set the `flex-direction` to `row` and, if you want them to have the same width, give all childs in your flex-container a `width` of `100%`.

See an example on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/EinLinuus/pen/WNxvwbo

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right, you want the nav items and the

tag to be side by side.

if you want to achieve this you could wrap the  's in there own section and apply flex-direction: row; to the

```css
nav
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
nav div
{
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;

}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <section class="main">
        <div><a href="">O mnie</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Moje projekty</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Galeria</a></div>
        <div><a href="">Kontakt</a></div>
    </section>
        <p>tekst tekst</p>
    </nav>
```

I hope this is what you are after. If note, can you explain a little more on what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your response. These divs in nav I would like to have for sure with flex-direction: column. The problem is that I cannot place <p> next to first div cause <p> is still in flex-direction: column and I cannot change that in any way,

Comment: I think the code I have given you achieves what you are looking for. If you want the <p> tag alongside the first <div> in you <nav> then you can align-items: flex-start; instead of center.  https://codepen.io/c-tregunna/pen/qBNdZEQ

Comment: Sorry but no. But I found the answer. I cannot achieve this with flex box.
You can see it at the begining of this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSIclWvNTdQ . I wanned to have one big div next to another few smaller like in css grid.